# i need to only the contacts from account and it's populate in b list,,

Tags: apex, soql

```
list<account> a = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account];
list<account> b = new list<account>();
for(account c:a)
{
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the forum. It is unclear what you are asking. You can't add Contacts to the Account list type. You will need a Contacts list.

Comment: @Ruban, can you reword your question title perhaps, also it is unclear what your are trying to achieve with your code example

Answer (score 2):

While your question is not very clear, I would suggest, based on the title, one of two things.

First, if you really want a list of all contacts from all accounts, you could do something like this (refactoring your code)

```
list<account> a = [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts) FROM Account];
list<Contact> b = new list<Contact>();
for(account c:a){
    b.addAll(c.Contacts);
}
```

That being said, if all you want is all contacts related to all accounts, you could also use this:

```
List<Contact> c = new List<Contact>([select id,name from Contact where accountid <> null]);
```

If you clarify your use case, the community will probably be able to provide a more accurate answer.